# Is there any such thing like CSS text-transform:uppercase for iOS UILabel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationBar` which title I would like to capitalize all letters so 'word' becomes 'WORD'.

I would like to do the same for buttons within this nav bar.

I was wondering if is there anything like CSS `text-transform:uppercase;` attribute where it is possible to change the visual appearance of the word but once retrieving its value it stills returning its raw value.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using `[myString uppercaseString]` has the downside of returning an uppercase string (well, it is not actually a downside ..) and not the  original string, one option would be to set a UILabel with an all-caps font (*Copperplate* is just an example of an all-caps font, you will likely find a better one):

```
int height = navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
int width = navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;

UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
navLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:18];
navLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
```

Comment: That is a good alternative tilo, thanks for the idea. While relying on the font itself this is good because it is not string manipulation, but just a visual aid.

Comment: @zanona What is wrong with string manipulation? `uppercaseString` doesn't even modify your original text, just makes an uppercase copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually simpler than you would think. You can use NSString's `uppercaseString` to achieve this.

```
[myLabel setText:[myString uppercaseString]];
```

Or, better suited to your needs:

```
for (UIBarButtonItem *button in self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems) { //Your nag bar
    [button setTitle:[[button title] uppercaseString]];
}
```

**EDIT:** Example of string not changing.

```
NSString *myString = @"hello";
NSString *mySecondString = @"world!";

UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[myString uppercaseString] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[mySecondString uppercaseString] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1,item2, nil]];

NSLog(@"%@ | %@",myString,mySecondString);//this will output the same as when it was originally created.
```

Comment: just replying your comment up there: but when retrieving `button.title` it will return `word` so you mean that after do `[button setTitle:[[button title] uppercaseString]]` then `button.title` will still return `word` and not `WORD`?

Comment: @zanona No, sorry, I meant the original string would return the same and I've added an example of such. I see the merit in the other way of doing this, I'm just trying to show you the options. I've edited my post to better explain what I meant.

Comment: +1 thank you! I see what you mean, that is really good too. Although I'm afraid this can't be related to css `text-transform` which only acts on the representational layer, but to javascript `toUpperCase()` instead. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

There is !

```
NSString *myLowercaseString = @"a lowercase string";
NSString *myUppercaseString = [myLowercaseString uppercaseString];
```

If you `NSLog (@"%@", myUppercaseString);`, you will get the following output :

> A LOWERCASE STRING

Then you can set your button's or your navigation bar's text property to your string.